# CSP error with Vite Build - Laravel/Inertiajs

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs, laravel-10

I have an app built with Laravel 10, Vuejs, Inertiajs and so Ziggy.
I have a problem when I try to build app for PROD with CSP nonce.

I follow the Laravel Doc (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#content-security-policy-csp-nonce), and I create Middleware.

I follow the Ziggy Doc (https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#using-routes-with-a-content-security-policy) and I add to my app.blade.php directive

```
@routes(nonce: 'your-nonce-here')
```

When I use

```
Vite dev
```

App works fine, all the functionality works, but when I try to build my app with

```
Vite build
```

I can open my app, and I can navigate my app only with URL bar, so if for example in my app I have a route "/plans", if I write in my Urlbar "mysite.test/plans", the app works correctly.
But when I try to click on inertia link, return many errors for load script like:

> Refused to load the script
> 'mysite.test/build/assets/Plans-7141c495.js' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src-elem 'nonce-Xtovi7dS0UISAWPSytfddh9SV0CjSA0RNQiRdzeu'".

I tried also, as DOC ziggy says Disabling the route() helper but nothing change, I have same errors:
https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#using-routes-with-a-content-security-policy

Now I have my App.blade.php

```
    @routes(nonce: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite::cspNonce())
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
```

And I have the middleware identical to the one in the official laravel documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using: [Laravel-csp](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp) from Spatie,

Make sure to also follow the Vite steps and use:

```
@routes(nonce: csp_nonce())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubles following the above, for me it worked by doing this:

Step 1: Create a new middleware:

```
class SecurityHeadersMiddleware
{
    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $nonce = base64_encode(random_bytes(22));

        $request->attributes->add(['csp_nonce' => $nonce]);

        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', "script-src 'self' 'nonce-{$nonce}'; object-src 'none'");

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add the middleware to your `kernel.php`

Step 3: Create a new provider

```
class NonceServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('csp_nonce', request()->attributes->get('csp_nonce'));
        });
    }
}
```

Step 4: Add the new provider to your `app.php`

Step 5: Add the nonce to your `@route`

```
<!-- Scripts -->
@routes(false, $csp_nonce)
```

This will basically, generate the nonce in the middleware and set the security rules with the nonce, store the nonce in the request and set the nonce through the provider which share it in all of your views, and lastly we set it in our ziggy routes :)